# Uncaught Exception in PHPExcel_Writer

Tags: php

When I am trying to export from PHP to excel,  PHPExcel is throwing an error called **could not close zip file**.

I have tried everything but it still doesn't work. Somebody please tell me the solution or any other alternative to export PHP to excel.

I tried this:

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=abc.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
echo $value;
```

$value contains the content which I want to download.

Comment: If you have tried everything, and nothing works, then it is pointless to keep trying. More seriously, show what you have tried and why it failed, along with any relevant exact error message you receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved]

I made use of session variable and redirected to another php page to export the data from variable.